# How do I generate update.rdf for the firefox addon-sdk?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

To provide auto updates for my plugin on my server, I need to create a `update.rdf` file.

How do I generate such a file?

The documentation is quite overwhelming: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extension_Versioning,_Update_and_Compatibility#Update_RDF_Format

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`cfx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx) tool with the `--update-link` and `--update-url` flags. This will generate `<addon name>.update.rdf`, ready to be uploaded to your server.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx#updateURL_and_updateLink:

> ## updateURL and updateLink
>
> If you choose to host the XPI yourself you should enable the host application to find new versions of your add-on.
>
> To do this, include a URL in the XPI called the updateURL: the host application will go here to get information about updates. At the updateURL you host a file in the update RDF format: among other things, this includes another URL called updateLink which points to the updated XPI itself.
>
> The `--update-link` and `--update-url` options simplify this process. Both options take a URL as an argument.
>
> The `--update-link` option builds an update RDF alongside the XPI, and embeds the supplied URL in the update RDF as the value of updateLink.
>
> The `--update-url` option embeds the supplied URL in the XPI file, as the value of updateURL.
>
> Note that as the [add-on documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/extension_versioning,_update_and_compatibility#Securing_Updates) explains, you should make sure the update procedure for your add-on is secure, and this usually involves using HTTPS for the links.
>
> So if we run the following command:
>
> ```
>  cfx xpi --update-link https://example.com/addon/latest/pluginName.xpi --update-url https://example.com/addon/update_rdf/pluginName.update.rdf
> ```
>
> `cfx` will create two files:
>
> - an XPI file which embeds `https://example.com/addon/update_rdf/pluginName.update.rdf` as the value of updateURL
> - an RDF file which embeds `https://example.com/addon/latest/pluginName.xpi` as the value of updateLink.

Comment: cfx is deprecated. What's the correct way to do this with JPM?

Answer (score 0):

`cfx` [has been deprecated since Firefox 38](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/02/26/jpm-replaces-cfx-for-firefox-38/) and replaced with a new tool called `jpm`.

According to the MDN article on [supporting updates for self-hosted add-ons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Supporting_updates_for_self-hosted_add-ons) in JPM, update manifest files are generated by JPM using the `jpm xpi` command when you include the `updateURL` and `updateLink` keys in your `package.json` file:

> To do this, include two extra keys in package.json:
>
> - updateURL: This URL is included in the install manifest of the XPI file that jpm xpi builds. It points to your update manifest. The
>     updateURL value may be HTTPS. If it is not, then you'll also need to
>     sign the update manifest, and then include the public key using the
>     updateKey field in package.json. See Securing updates for more on
>     this.
> - updateLink: This URL is included in the update manifest file. It points to the XPI, and must be an HTTPS URL.

For more on this, see the MDN article on [Supporting updates for self-hosted add-ons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Supporting_updates_for_self-hosted_add-ons).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use `jpm xpi` and the the `jpm sign` with the `--xpi` argument pointing to the newly created `.xpi` file.

The `jpm xpi` comment creates the `update.rdf` file.

THE PROBLEM IS THAT THE `update.rdf` FILE IS NOT CORRECT.

- The ':extension' is missing in the about attribute of the description element.

SOME WAY TO TROUBLESHOOT.

- Rename the unsigned `.xpi` file to `.zip` and check the contents to include the update URLs in the automatically generated `install.rdf` file.
- Go to `about:config` in FF and update `extensions.logging.enabled` to `true`. Now view the console and look for errors when updating.

Hope this helps.